# How to update value of a key in object in an array with the new value in React useState in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that gets input as the name of the input filed and the value of that input field as

```
function handleChange(e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void{
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const key = name
    let newArr = [...form];
    newArr.map(item => {
      return {...form , [key]: value}
    });

    setForm(newArr)
  }
```

The structure of the default view is like this:

```
    const form = [{
  "Name":"Nagesh",
  "Email":"abc@gmail.com",
  "Address" : {
    "House_Number":"123",
    "Street_Name":"something",
    "City":"example",
  },
  "Phone_Number":"567899090"
}]
```

Now after hitting the `onChange` event, I receive the name of the input field and the value of the current input field to the `handleChange` function. The issue is `newArr` doesn't update the old value with the new value and doesn't update the state with new values.

For example if I pass the value to `name` as the name of the input field which is 'Name' and its value as 'Nagesh Katna', it gets the values but doesn't update the newArr's filed `[{"Name": "Nagesh Katna"}]`

If I `console.log(newArr)`. The array stays with the default values. I am using TypeScript and semantic-UI as the frontend.

I have defined an interface with the same structure for form and using the states in a way

```
  const defaultView: Values[] = []
  const [form, setForm]: [Values[], (fetch: Values[]) => void] = useState(defaultView);
```

Please save my weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new array here, a shallow copy of the `form`:

```
let newArr = [...form];
```

And you're mapping over it to create another new array here:

```
newArr.map(item => {
  return {...form , [key]: value}
});
```

But you never use the result of the `.map`. You need to assign it to a variable, and pass that to `setForm`.

Also, the `{ ...form` is probaly a typo - did you mean `{ ...item`?

```
const newForm = newArr.map(item => {
  return {...item , [key]: value}
});
setForm(newForm);
```

More concisely:

```
setForm(
    form.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        [name]: value
    }))
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answere. No there isn't a typo. I tried so many different things but none worked so I just pasted the last thing I tried. I am giving a try to your solution.

Comment: It looks like a typo, since it doesn't make sense - `form` is an array, not an object, so spreading the `form` array into an object to return is nonsensical.

Comment: Your solution did work. As I said I tried so many things that I got lost on track of what I did. I can see how it was nonsensical of using the form.